How to use .navigationDestination(for: and .navigationDestination(isPresented: together
How can I achieve this type of Navigation:

So I've written this code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var goArchive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(value: 1) {  // <- Navigation Type #1
                    Text("First Level")
                }
                
                Button("Go to Archive") {
                    goArchive = true        // <- Navigation Type #2
                }
                
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { level in    // <- Navigation Type #1
                LevelView(level: level)
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $goArchive) {   // <- Navigation Type #2
                ArchiveView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LevelView: View {
    let level: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Level = \(level)!")
    }
}

struct ArchiveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Archive View!")
            
            NavigationLink(value: 1) {
                Text("First View")
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem that I encounter is: when I open the ArchiveView and select LevelView - I am navigated to LevelView (first), but immediately to ArchiveView again!? What am I doing wrong?
P.S. The only similar question I've found is this one, and the comment says: "You need to update the isPresented value otherwise it always comes back...". How can I update the goArchive variable?

its easier to make some model types for what you want to show before you use navigationDestination so you can make full use of the value feature

It seems like navigation destinations overlapped each other. You better use NavigationPath in this scenario, it should be:
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath() //<- here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) { //<- here
            VStack {
                Button {
                    path.append(1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Level View")
                }

                Button {
                    path.append("Archive")
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to Archive")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { level in
                LevelView(level: level)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { archive in
                ArchiveView(path: $path)
            }
        }
    }
}

Leaving LevelView as it is, and binding path to ArchiveView. You also do not need to implement .navigationDestination because Int type was in MainView.
struct ArchiveView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath //<- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Archive View!")

            Button {
                path.append(1)
            } label: {
                Text("First View")
            }
        }
    }
}

Output


I wanted to avoid using $path in such a simple app, but your code works and looks like it's the way to go. Thank you!

IMO I think this is what it was designed for along with NavigationStack, every piece will present a single source of truth theory.
